# Delete SourceTree Commit History

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using [`SourceTree`](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) and I checked out an existing project. For testing purposes I did a commit. It shows up in the commit history. How do I clean this history once again? Reverting the change makes another entry in the history but I want the history to just contain the initial commit.

Why is easy history management not such a basic feature or maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You can reset to the last commit you want to keep. Use the "hard" option and the history after this will be removed. This is normaly not an good idea when the commit is pushed, then reverting is more suitable.

[image]